# Проблема при добавлении кириллицы

Tags: java, кодировка, кириллица

В папке лежат текстовые файлы (внутри латиница+кириллица). Одни в кодировке UTF-8, другие в ANSI. Мне нужно их считывать, изменять некоторые строки и переписывать в другую папку.

При считывании для определения кодировки использую `org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector` .
Считываю в `ArrayList<String>` через  `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInput, Charset.forName(decoder.getDetectedCharset())));`

Потом в массиве добавляю нужные строки  и записываю в новый файл через  `FileWriter`

Просто считать/поменять что-то на латинице/перезаписать работает хорошо для всех строк.
Проблема возникает, если меняю строку на кириллице.  Тогда при записи в новый файл, считанная кириллица, да и часть добавленной  идет абракадаброй

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В IDEA File Encodings стоит windows-1251.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать кодировку UTF-8

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]